# How to call a stored procedure using ABP framework multi tenancy

Tags: .net, abp

```
 string sql = 'EXEC SP_GetProducts @lastUpdated, @ProductName";
    
List<SqlParameter> params = new List<SqlParameter>{ new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@lastUpdated",  Value = ....},  new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@ProductName",  Value = ....} }
    ......
    
    context.products.FromSqlRaw<Product>(sql, params.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
```

I am using the ABP framework in my webapi and implemented multi tenancy. Every other database calls are working fine except the stored procedure call.

Sometimes it is fetching data from wrong tenant.
Weird thing is `context.Database.GetConnectionString()` confirms that context is referring to correct tenant database.

Please suggest what needs to be done to make it work.

Comment: Are the parameters in the right order? You are passing them by ordinal, rather than by name

Comment: Updated my original post for your reference. and none of the parameter is related to tenant .  I have one host and couple of tenants. To test certain scenarios I am logging out  and logging in from one tenant to another tenant or host. And under these circumstances what I notice is that, the stored procedure is fetching data from a different tenant database than the currently logged in tenant. And this is happening only in case of stored procedure.

Comment: Show your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: The problem is definitely not related to stored procedure definition. I even tried with a simple definition -   `CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetProducts @lastUpdated datetime2, @ProductName varchar2
AS
SELECT * FROM Customers
GO;`

Comment: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Multi-Tenancy - In our case we are creating separate database for each tenant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community   I think I have clearly specified my problem. I am using ABP framework and its a multitenant application.  All tenants have separate databases. When I am calling stored procedure the stored procedure is sometimes (not always) fetching data from another tenant database instead of current tenant database. But in case you think any specific additional information would be helpful to resolve this issue, please let me know, will definitely try my best to provide those information as well.

Comment: I think you need to add more logs and find out if the Unit of Work is being created properly